# How to allocate an object with a complex constructor?

Tags: c++, memory-management, raii

I think I know C++ reasonably well and I am thinking about implementing something a bit bigger than a "toy" program. I know the difference between stack- and heap-memory and the RAII-idiom.

Lets assume I have a simple class *point*:

```
class point {
public:
    int x;
    int y;
    point(int x, int y) : x(x), y(y) {}
};
```

I would allocate points always on the stack, since the objects are small. Since on 64-bit machines `sizeof(point) == sizeof(void*)`, if a am not wrong, I would go even further and pass points by value by default.

Now lets assume a more complex class *battlefield*, that I want to use in the class *game*:

```
class battlefield {
public:
    battlefield(int w, int h, int start_x, int start_y, istream &in) {
        // Complex generation of a battlefield from a file/network stream/whatever.
    }
};
```

Since I really like RAII and the automatic cleanup when an object leaves the scope I am tempted to allocate the battlefield on the stack.

```
game::game(const settings &s) :
        battlefield(s.read("w"), s.read("h"), gen_random_int(), gen_random_int(), gen_istream(s.read("level_number"))) {
    // ...
}
```

But I have several problems now:

- Since this class has not got a zero-args-constructor I have to initialize it in the initialisation list of the class I use battlefield in. This is cumbersome since I need a istream from somewhere. This leads to the next problem.
- The complex constructors "snowball" at some point. When I use *battlefield* in the *game* class and initialize it in the initialisation list the constructor of *game*, the constructor of game will become fairly complex too and the initialisation of *game* itself might become cumbersome too. (When I decide to take the *istream* as argument of the *game* constructor)
- I need auxiliary functions to fill in complex parameters.

I see two solutions to this problem:

- Either I create a simple constructor for *battlefield* that does not initialize the object. But this approach has the problem that I have a half-initialized object, aka an object that violates the RAII-idiom. Strange things might happen when calling methods on such an object.

  ```
  game::game(const settings &s) {
      random_gen r;
      int x = r.random_int();
      int y = r.random_int();
      ifstream in(s.read("level_number"));
      in.open();
      this->battlefield.init(s.read("w"), s.read("h"), x, y, in);
      // ...
  }
  ```
- Or I allocate *battlefield* on the heap in the *game* constructor. But I have to beware of exceptions in the constructor and I have to take care that the destructor deletes the *battlefield*.

  ```
  game::game(const settings &s) {
      random_gen r;
      int x = r.random_int();
      int y = r.random_int();
      ifstream in(s.read("level_number"));
      in.open();
      this->battlefield = new battlefield(s.read("w"), s.read("h"), x, y, in);
      // ...
  }
  ```

I hope you can see the problem I am thinking of. Some questions that arise for me are:

- Is there a design pattern for this situations I do not know?
- What is the best practise in bigger C++ projects? Which objects are allocated on the heap, which ones are allocated on the stack? Why?
- What is the general advice regarding the complexity of constructors? Is reading from a file too much for a constructor? (Since this problem mostly arises from the complex constructor.)

Comment: By the way, the term "stack" you use here is misleading; when you create an object as a member of another class you're not allocating it on the stack, but wherever the parent object is allocated. If `battlefield` is allocated on the heap ("the freestore" in C++ terminology) then all its subobjects will be on the heap.

Comment: "Since on 64-bit machines sizeof(point) == sizeof(void*), if a am not wrong" - you **are** wrong; `int` is guaranteed to be *at least* 32 bit type, but it's completely implementation defined. It can be 64 bit as well. Also, "stack" and "heap" are not defined in C++ standard; you wanted to mention "automatic" and "dynamic" storage, as stack and heap are implementation detail.

Comment: "`int` is guaranteed to be at least 32-bit" - really?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could let your battlefield be constructed from settings:

```
explicit battlefield(const settings& s);
```

or alternatively, why not create a factory function for your `battlefield`?

E.g.

```
battlefield CreateBattlefield(const settings& s)
{
    int w = s.read("w");
    int h = s.read("w");
    std::istream& in = s.genistream();
    return battlefield(w, h, gen_random_int(), gen_random_int(), in);
}

game::game(const settings &s) :
    battlefield(CreateBattlefield(s)) {
    // ...
}
```

Comment: So basically you say, that I should try to refactor the constructor if I have an especially complex one and if this is not possible I should write a factory function. Am I right when I assume, that when there is a well-defined move-constructor in `battlefield` your factory function does not create any unnecessary copies of `battlefield`?

Comment: In the case of the former, a well-behaved move constructor will not be affected.  As an aside, you said that you need a lot of things in order to create your battlefield.  If those are concurrent activities, in principle, then you can view the creation of the settings object as enforcing a join point before you proceed to battlefield construction.  In the case of the latter, you should make your constructors private, in which case you can't have well-defined move constructor. Implement move semantics as a factory method.

Answer (score 2):

> But this approach has the problem that I have a half-initialized object, aka an object that violates the RAII-idiom.

That is not *RAII*. The concept is you use objects to manage the resources. When you aquire a resource like heap memory, semaphore, file handle, you have to transfer the ownership to a resource managing class. This is what smart pointers in C++ are meant for. You have to use either `unique_ptr` if you want to have sole ownership of the object or use a `shared_ptr` if you want multiple pointers to have ownership.

> Or I allocate battlefield on the heap in the game constructor. But I have to beware of exceptions in the constructor and I have to take care that the destructor deletes the battlefield.

If your constructor throws an exception, then the destructor of the object would not be called and you might end up in a half-cooked object. In this case, you have to remember what allocations you did in the constructor before the exception was thrown and deallocate all those. Again *smart pointers* will help automatic cleaning of resources. See this [faq](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/exceptions.html#faq-17.10)

> Which objects are allocated on the heap, which ones are allocated on the stack? Why?

Try to allocate the objects in stack whenever possible. Your objects then have life only in the scope of that block. If you have a case where this is not possible go for heap allocation - eg: you only know the size at runtime, the size of the object is too big to sit on stack.